# What does the square bracket after the number mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Such as `2[a]`, whose value is `undefined`.

The code bellow will get an error `Cannot access 'b' before initialization`

```js
let a = 1, b = 2
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

I know it caused by the missing semicolon after the `b = 2`. And after the semicolon has been added

```js
let a = 1, b = 2;
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

It works fine. Is it caused by the square bracket after the number? If so, what is the meaning of it in javascript?

Comment: @Pointy It's a property access, that's why its not a syntax but a runtime error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it caused by the square bracket after the number?

Yes.

> If so, what is the meaning of it in javascript?

It's a property access operation, just like:

```js
const array = [1, 2, 3];

const b = array[1];
//             ^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−

console.log(b); // 2
```

You can do property access operations on primitives, and in fact you often do. For instance, on a string primitive:

```js
console.log("hi".toUpperCase()); // "HI"

// or

const fiftyFifty = Math.random() < 0.5;
const method = fiftyFifty ? "toUpperCase" : "toLowerCase";

console.log("Hi"[method]()); // "hi" or "HI"
```

Or using a number primitive:

```js
console.log(2["toString"]()); // "2"

const n = 2;
console.log(n.toString());    // "2"

console.log(2..toString());   // "2"
```

When you do, the relevant prototype is used (`String.prototype`, `Number.prototype`, etc.) and in loose mode in some situations a temporary object is created (e.g., `new String("hi")` or `new Number(2)`).

Comment: Why not demonstrate `2["toString"]()`?

Comment: @Bergi - I did originally, but people don't "often" do that. :-) They often do `let n = 2; n.toString()`, but not `2["toString"]()` (or `2..toString()`), so I figured something more familiar might be better...

Comment: I'll do both/and. :-)